# How to update a particular occurrence of column value which is separated by delimiter in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

Column value example `abc~ab123~4~abc124~asd`

I need to update the value after the second occurrence of `~` which is 4 to XYZ

Expected output  `abc~ab123~XYZ~abc124~asd`

Comment: Please, post sample data as something that may be treated as table (not some list with ~), show your current code and describe what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this works for you:

```
select 
    regexp_replace('abc~ab123~4~abc124~asd', 
                   '[^~]+',
                   'XYZ', 1, 3)
from dual
```

Comment: This worked for me , thanks